# Formatting a filename for fopen

Tags: c++, file

I've got a function which reads in a filename from command line and then attempts to open the file and parse it. However `fopen` always returns null with error codes 2, 3, or 123 depending on the filename given.

The original non working code is:

```
void CProfiler::ExecuteIrFile( LPCTSTR pszFile)
{
    FILE    *fp = fopen( pszFile, "r");
    if ( !fp) return;
}
```

Changing to `fopen( "c:\\temp\\file.txt", "r")` does however work. 
So I've been led to believe that its a problem with escaping in the string i'm passing to `fopen`

Replacing `\` with `\\` in the string does'nt work either though. For good measure the code I used to do that is:

```
CString tempStr(pszFile);
tempStr.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
FILE *fp = fopen( tempStr, "r");
```

Is their a method of escaping a string properly for fopen, or something else i'm missing?
Uncomplicated answers would be welcomed happily as I haven't used C++ for very much at all in the past.

---

### Solved

I had a leading space in the string getting passed, the resolution on the screen with the debugger on was too low and thus did'nt notice the space until I tried printing the string out to a file as binary.
Thanks all for your help

Comment: You should first check the content of pszFile. The file name for `fopen` do need any escape.

Comment: If I write `c:\\temp\\file.txt` to a CString and compare that and the contents of pszFile, they appear identical

Comment: Are you compiling for Unicode or ANSI? (I assume ANSI if the example code compiles ok since fopen takes a char*). I think you need to post your command line parsing code.

Comment: @Bodyloss: Identical with regard to terminal output or byte-wise identical? There might be a stray \r in there before the terminator byte, which you'd never find by printing the string to a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `/` in windows filenames - it's easier since you can replace single characters without having to change the string length.

eg. `"c:/temp/file.txt"` instead of `"c:\\temp\\file.txt"`